# Apache ProxyPass adding Port only on base URL

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

This is getting frustrating to say the least haha.

I have setup a proxypass and proxypassreverse in apache under virtual host 443 to proxy to nginx running in a container on port 8443.

This is all I have set up to do this

```
CustomLog /srv/apps/ktech-connect/log/apache/custom.log combined
ErrorLog /srv/apps/ktech-connect/log/apache/errors.log

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
ProxyPass        / https://127.0.0.1:8443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8443/
```

When I hit any url such as example.com/page it works like it should
But when I go to example.com or even example.com/ it will show a redirect from apache to example.com:8443 in the url.

I have tried adding ProxyPreserveHost but it does nothing, and a whole host of other options. I just don't understand where the redirect is coming from and the fact that it only happens when hitting the base url.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ServerFault, It was an old rewrite directive still in my browser cache lol. Cleared it and now it works as expected.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with you to clean?